# unblocked scanner function java

Tags: java

I would like to ask to the user if he could press a key before continuing. Then my program will wait for that during 10 seconds. 
If nothing is done, then, I would like to be able to exit the program.

My problem is that the function scanner block my program (until the user have pressed a key) and doesn't allow the program to execute the end.

Do you have any idea of what I could do/use instead of scanner? I am just a beginner in java so please, be indulgent with me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test{
    public Test(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         boolean first = true;
         System.out.println("Press any key to start.\n"); 
        for(int fr = 0; fr <11; fr++){
            System.out.println(fr);
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("error -> "+e.getMessage()); // in case of exception, error message
                }
        if(fr == 10){
            Default def = new Default();
        }else if(scan.hasNext() == true){
            //System.out.println("Hello");
            User user = new User(); // or exit, it doesn't matter
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the android tag is not a mistake, you need to re-design your program to display on the android ui, and to be a collection of brief-in-time methods called from android's event-driven ui.  Start over with some basic android examples and work from there back towards your goal.

Comment: I think you added the Android tag by mistake, because the code doesn't even relate to android.

Comment: There is answer in the following question which you may be able to adapt to your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872846/how-to-read-from-standard-input-non-blocking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html).

First make a [Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html), give it the focus, and add a KeyListener.

Example code:

```
Component comp = new Componenet();
comp.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.print("Hello");
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
});

try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (Exception e) {
}
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am looking for ways to create a component. I think your code is not very close of what I want... Is it possible to juste replace "scan.hasNext()" by the keyListener ? I am a little bit lost, sorry.

Comment: @Beginner To create a component, simply put `Component comp = new Component()` (the top line here). Then, when a key is pressed, it triggers the event keyTyped(), which does whatever you want (in this case print "Hello"). This can be instead of the `scan.hasNext()`.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is using a different thread to read user input from the scanner. Here is an example code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
ExecutorService scannerExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<String> nextLineFuture = scannerExecutor.submit(scanner::nextLine);
/* For Java < 8:
Future<String> nextLineFuture = scannerExecutor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return scanner.nextLine();
    }
});
 */

String input;
try {
    input = nextLineFuture.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
catch (TimeoutException e) {
    input = "Nothing was entered";
}
catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    // Handle the exception
    return;
}

System.out.println(input);
```

However, you need to keep in mind some of the issues with this:

- Even when `nextLineFuture.get(...)` throws `TimeoutException`, the `nextLine` call will still be running. If you later run `scannerExecutor.submit(scanner::nextLine)` again, the input will first be consumed by the previous call, so you should make sure to have a reference to the last `Future` created whose result hasn't been used yet.
- Because of the issue above, this approach will not work if you need to use different scanner methods such as `nextBoolean`, `nextInt`, etc. You can, however, always use `nextLine` on the primary scanner and then parse the line manually (for example, by using yet another scanner)

Comment: I will try your method, but I don't understand the third line. Can you explain it to me a little bit more ?

Comment: What exactly does confuse you? It uses [method references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) (Java 8+), I added alternative code to my answer.

Comment: I am working on eclipse, and it doesn't know the third line, send me back an error message.

Comment: Try to comment out the third line, and instead uncomment the block I added in the last edit.