# How to receive messages from server to client, without prompt from client

Tags: java, server, client

So I am making a basic chat application. This is a snippet of the code from the client. Here I am sending information to the server and then getting a reply.

However, sometimes the server will send messages to the client without requiring the client to send information to the server first. How do I implement this?

```
while (true){    
        String sentence;
        BufferedReader inFromUser =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        sentence = inFromUser.readLine();

        // send to server
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        outToServer.writeBytes("\n");

        // create read stream and receive from server
        BufferedReader FromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println(FromServer.readLine());


    }
```

For example, the server might send random bits of information to me at random intervals. But I can only receive them when I send the server something first. But if I implement something likes this instead (shown below), I will no longer be able to send information to the server and can only act as a receiver. But I want to be able to send information and receive information when necessary without having to send something first.

```
while (true){    

        // receive from server only
        BufferedReader FromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println(FromServer.readLine());


    }
```

What I changed in reply to first comment. I followed your code so this is what I did. However, i still can't seem to receive messages spontaneously ie i still need to press enter or type in an input to receive any server information sent at random times:

```
BufferedReader FromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    while (true) {  
        // Check if there's anything to receive
        while (FromServer.ready()) {
            // receive from server
            System.out.println(FromServer.readLine());
        }

        String sentence;
        BufferedReader inFromUser =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        sentence = inFromUser.readLine();

        // write to server
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');

// Send data to the server here if required.
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to something like this:-

```
BufferedReader FromServer = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader inFromUser =
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

while (true) {  
    // Check if there's anything to receive
    while (FromServer.ready()) {
        // receive from server
        System.out.println(FromServer.readLine());
    }
    if (inFromUser.ready()) {
        int ch = inFromUser.read();

        // write to server
        outToServer.writeChar(ch);
    }


}
```

Now the client will read anything that's there to be read, and can send data if/when required.

Comment: hmm still doesnt seem to work when i added the code snippet to the bottom. I still need to press enter to receive any messages from the server

Comment: I'll edit my post and show you what I added to the bottom

Comment: There must be some code preventing your client from getting to this part of the code.

Comment: i can receive and send all messages to the server, but the server will sometimes send random alerts or messages. I am unable to get these alerts automatically, only when I press enter or send a message first do i get a reply.

Comment: You're getting input from the keyboard using Scanner, so the code is waiting for you to press enter (at the line `inFromUser.readLine()`.  You need to change the way you receive input; it's probably easiest to do it in another thread, or create a form.

Comment: hmm im not using scanner though. yeh i guess not really too sure about how to do this since im not that familiar with threading.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I was rushing.  The problem is still the same though.  I've edited my answer which I've not tested but might work.  EDIT: According to this answer, you'll need a sep thread to read from the keyboard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872846/how-to-read-from-standard-input-non-blocking

Comment: Okay, one more edit: It will now send each char as the user types it in.  AFAIK this is the only way to avoid blocking without using threads. :)

Comment: ok thanks so much for everything!!  I think your solution kinda works! But I will need to do more testing. but thankyou

Comment: No probs, I like an interesting challenge. :)