# How do I stop and skip a command after 3.5 seconds?

Tags: java, loops, timer

I want to stop and skip a command while it's waiting for input after 3.5 seconds. I have tried to use `System.currentTimeMillis()` by subtracting from the start time, however the code I made does not skip the input.

food is an arrayList from the table class.

```
public void timer() {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        while(false||(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime)<3500)
        {
            correct = input(); //What I want to skip after 3.5 seconds
        }
        record();
    }
```

Here is the `input()` method:

```
public boolean input() 
    {
        Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

        //I want to skip everything after this after 3.5 seconds.

        int num = console.nextInt(); 
        num--;
        System.out.println("You selected " + table.food.get(num).toString());
        table.food.remove(num);
        if (num==choice) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: The code you have written repeatedly asks for input for 3.5 seconds; is that what you want?

Comment: No, I want it to stop asking for input and skip the code after 3.5 seconds

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to read from standard input non-blocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872846/how-to-read-from-standard-input-non-blocking)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the problems you are facing is that any of the `Scanner`'s `next` methods can not be interrupted when reading from a console. Therefore you have to read the input in a different way, for example by using a `InputStreamReader`.

After that you can submit a specific task to a [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) that handels the execution of the "input reading" seperately from the `main Thread`. You will get a [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) on which you can define a timeout.

Note that this operation is still blocking (on both threads).

This solution is somewhat based on this [`article`](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue153.html).

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Test {
    static class ReadInput implements Callable<Integer> {

        public Integer call() throws IOException {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            try {
                while (br.ready() == false) {
                    Thread.sleep(250);
                }

                String input = br.readLine();
                return Integer.parseInt(input);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer input = null;
        ExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        try {
            Future<Integer> future = ex.submit(new ReadInput());
            input = future.get(3500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | TimeoutException e) {
            // handle exceptions that need to be handeled
        } finally {
            ex.shutdownNow();
        }

        System.out.println("done: " + input);
    }
}
```

Note that timeout in the `ReadInput` should be lower than the timeout in the `main Thread`.

Comment: Hey, I really appreciate the effort you put in trying to help me. However, I'm quite new (just started AP CS) and wanted further understanding on what this code is and does.

Comment: Yes, we haven't learned static yet (which is surprising, I know). So like, do I make another class to put the first block of code in or do I do it below all my code? And I started this project before I learned Eclipse, so its in blueJ, will it still work? And sorry for asking you all this, but could you please elaborate on how this works?

Comment: The `static` is not really relevant in this case (I just used it as I created this as an [`inner class`](https://www.javatpoint.com/static-nested-class) next to the main method). Feel free to create a `public class` (in its own file) instead. -- I've never used `blueJ` but its just basic java code, not really related to any `IDE`.

Comment: I put it under my class and it says modifier static not allowed here

Comment: I have added a main class (`Test`), now you can simply copy it.

Comment: [link](https://pastebin.com/KEB3gWsx)

I modified it to this and when it returns input after time runs out it gives me a null pointer exception, how would I fix this? @second

Comment: Integer is an object, that might be null. The [`unboxing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to a primitive int causes the `NullPointerExcetpion`, because a primitive can't be null. Add an `if (input == null) return -1` (or any other indicator that the user did not input anything) or change the return type of the method to `Integer`.